# Does javascript date have dependency on the client device?

Tags: javascript, date, client

If the time difference between the two devices is 1 second, will the time obtained through new Date() from each devices be 1 second difference?

Comment: [The user's device provides the local time.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: If the times of 2 devices is 1 second out, then one of them or both is wrong.   Technically if all devices have the correct time set, then all devices in the world will have the same time in UTC..

Comment: ECMAScript gets date and time values from the system, so as far as it's concerned, the time is whatever the system says it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes date depends upon client's device in javascript.